# Memory mapped I/O on the riscv rocket core

Tags: riscv

How can I do uncached memory accesses on the rocket?  Is there a way to specify which regions of the memory map that should have caches enabled or disabled?

I can not find anything about this in any documentation, but if I have overlooked something I would be happy to receive a link to where this is documented.

Asbjørn

Answer (score 2):

This was answered on the riscv sw-dev mailing list. It is not possible to do uncached memory access on the rocket core.

https://lists.riscv.org/lists/arc/sw-dev/2014-10/msg00025.html :

> Rocket's data cache doesn't support uncached loads and stores.  Our test chips perform I/O using control registers via the CSRxx instructions.